# how can I write file to windows system folder?

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to add new fonts to my windows system folder by electron, but failed, how could I do this? here is the code which can work well in app folder.I just want to put the file in to 'c:\windows\Fonts', thank u.

```js
var request = http.get("http://www.mysites.com/newfont.ttf", function(response) {
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
   var file = fs.createWriteStream("app/font.ttf");
   response.pipe(file);
  }
 });
```

Comment: What does _"but failed"_ mean, specifically? Also, I can imagine that writing to the system folder requires admin privileges.

Comment: yes, I can not find the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your error you can see that http is not defined, that to tell you that you probably forget to `require` the `http` module. By the way you will have to do same thing with `fs` module no ?

Comment: thanks for answer, but it is not the problem. I add that modules, the problem is I can not write file to windows system folder.